# How to continue a php script after using exit() / die()

Tags: php, image, for-loop, rgb, exit

For example i have the following script.

in this case i want to get the value of X1 and Y1
but the the exit() is not letting me to do so

please help
thanks in advance
and special thanks to Mark Setchell :P (if he sees this)

[image link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwK-syg5gJTob1RIa2J1SXdtVW8/view?usp=sharing)

```
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("omr.jpg");
for($x=0;$x<100;$x++)   {

    for($y=0;$y<100;$y++)   
                            {

$rgb = imagecolorat($im,$x,$y);
      $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
      $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
      $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
      if($r<128 && $g<128 && $b<128){
         printf("%d,%d: %d,%d,%d\n",$x,$y,$r,$g,$b);
         exit;
                                    }
                            }
                        }

 for($x1=1170;$x1<1270;$x1++){

 for($y1=0;$y1<100;$y1++){

          $rgb = imagecolorat($im,$x1,$y1);

          $r1 = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
          $g1 = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
          $b1 = $rgb & 0xFF;
          if($r1<128 && $g1<128 && $b1<128){
          printf("%d,%d: %d,%d,%d\n",$x1,$y1,$r1,$g1,$b1);
          exit;
        }
       }
    }
```

> current output :
>   30,53: 123,119,118
>
> Desired output :
>   30,53: 123,119,118
>
> 1217,55: 115,114,112

Comment: So why are you using exit/die then?  "Output a message and __terminate__ the current script".... which part of "terminate" don't you understand?

Comment: Exit is not the right function. I guess you need break, or return.

Comment: actually i am a newbie in php
and i even don't know all the functions of php!
so i asked
but some voted me ngtv! :3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `break 2;` to break from two nested for loops and your next for loop for `x1` and `y1` will also execute.

Comment: Very well spotted. + 1

Answer (score 1):

[exit](http://php.net/exit)

> exit — Output a message and terminate the current script

**[die](http://php.net/die)**

> die — Equivalent to exit

Hence, you cannot do that, period. You can however rethink your solution where you don't have to use exit there because you want to continue the execution then `exit` is in the wrong place.

Now for the solution: You can break out of your loop when your condition is met.

**[break](http://php.net/break)**

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

That way your loop will end and you will be able to move on to your next loop without exit.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, it's not possible.

```
exit;              // equal to:    die;
exit();            // equal to:    die();
exit('I died');    // equal to:    die('I died');
```

are language construct designed to kill PHP process. As the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) says:

> Output a message and terminate the current script

Don't use it if you want script to continue.

In loops you can use two costructs you may be interested in:

[`break;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) - Immediately ends loop and continues code after the loop
[`continue;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) - Immediately skips current loop iteration and goes to the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the `die()` or `exit()`, you should instead use the `break` function. [Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), for more info.

`exit()` or and `die()` should be used only if you want to end the script.

> exit — Output a message and terminate the current script docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).
>
> die — Equivalent to exit, docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

depending on your scope , you can use break 1 or break 2,

```
$i = 0;
    while (++$i) {
        switch ($i) {
        case 5:
            echo "At 5<br />\n";
            break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
        case 10:
            echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
            break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a script after `die()` or `exit()` until unless you use condition or switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run a background php process if you wish to continue running scripts after a page has been rendered, unless you're asking to just run more changes to the page when a for loop has been terminated, in this case a `break;` would be best.

[stack overflow php background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)